# Numerically evaluating Young integral

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods

The Young integral is an extension of the standard Riemann-Stieltjes integral. Young (1936) showed that if $f$ has bounded $p$-variation and $g$ has bounded $q$-variation and that they have no common discontinuities and $1/p + 1/q > 1$, then the function
$$t \mapsto \int_0^t f\mathrm{d}g \tag{1}$$
exists and has finite $p$-variation.

Using this integral, one can solve (and give meaning to) differential equations driven by irregular paths, of the form
$$\mathrm{d}Y_t = f(Y_t)\mathrm{d}X_t,  \tag{2}$$
Where $Y_t$ is the unknown, $f$ is a function or a vector field and $X_t$ is in my case a path ('realization') of a continuous stochastic process. Assume that $f$ and $X_t$ satisfy the necessary conditions stated above, how can I numerically evaluate $(1)$?

To make it more specific, assume that $X_t$ is a continuous path of a fractional Brownian motion (fBM) with Hurst parameter $H > 0.5$ and $f$ can be any suitable non-constant function.

I know that the theory of Rough Paths is more general solution and that there is a [C++ package available](https://coropa.sourceforge.io/) to evaluate those. But since this theory is quite involved (and only really necessary for the case that $X_t$ has bounded $p$-variation with $p \geq 2$) , I wonder if there is an easier way to do this more restricted case.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you for the references, they have definitely helped me! If you can post your comment as an answer I will accept it!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Migrated from my comment)*

I know little about this topic, but considering that Young integral is also the limit of Riemann-Stieltjes sum I humbly guess that [*Euler approximation scheme*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maruyama_method) would work.

It seems to me that [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.6471.pdf) and the references therein (such as [this](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540758723)) address this topic.